# Angle bisector contains the Nine Point Centre

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I got a question recently, and have been unable to solve it.

> $\Delta ABC$ is a non-isosceles triangle with $\angle C=41°$.  $M$ is the midpoint of the segment joining the orthocentre $H$ and circumcentre $O$. If $AM$ bisects $\angle A$, find $\angle HAO$.

I proved that $AM\perp HO$, and $M$ is the nine-point-centre, but I can't find the required angle.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your work we obtain $AO=AH$ or in the standard notation
$$R=a|\cot\alpha|$$ or
$$\frac{a|\cos\alpha|}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{a}{2\sin\alpha}$$ or
$$|\cos\alpha|=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: How is $R=a|\cot\alpha|$? The rest I can understand, but not this.

Comment: Just $AO=R$ and $AH=a|\cot\alpha|$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

- $O, H$ are the **isogonal conjugate points** with respect to $\triangle
     ABC$.
- $ON=\dfrac{1}{2}AH$,where $N$ is the midpoint of $BC$.